# Vertx HttpClientRequest handler behavior test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, vert.x

I have a method which creates a HttpClientRequest instance and associates a Handler to it.

```
public void sendRequest(String requestId, File file, Message<A> message) {

        final HttpClientRequest request = getHttpClientRequest();
        request.putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE.toString(), FORM_DATA);
        request.putHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT.toString(), APPNEXUS_JSON_HEADER);
        request.putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING.toString(), "binary");
        final Buffer buffer = this.getBody(file.getAbsolutePath());
        request.putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH.toString(), String.valueOf(buffer.length()));
        request.handler(httpClientResponse -> {
          switch (httpClientResponse.statusCode()) {
            case Status.SC_OK:
              httpClientResponse.bodyHandler(body -> {
                 // Do something
              });
              break;
            case Status.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS:
              // Do  something
              break;
            default:
              // Do something
          }
        });}
```

The client request is to a 3rd party service. How should I write the unit test to invoke different clauses of the handler? I am using Mockito for mocking tasks.

Test that I have written so far,

> ```
> public void testSomething (TestContext testContext) { 
>       final Async async = testContext.async();
>       Mockito.when(httpClientRequest.exceptionHandler(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(httpClientRequest);
>       Mockito.when(httpClientRequest.putHeader(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(httpClientRequest);
>       Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
>         return httpClientResponse;      
>       }).when(httpClientRequest).end(Mockito.any(Buffer.class)); 
>       Mockito.when(routingContext.response()).thenReturn(httpServerResponse);
>       Mockito.when(routingContext.statusCode()).thenReturn(200);
>       Mockito.when(routingContext.getBody()).thenReturn(buffer);   
>       JsonObject jsonObject = Mockito.mock(JsonObject.class);
>       Mockito.when(buffer.toJsonObject()).thenReturn(jsonObject);                          Mockito.when(jsonObject.mapTo(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(appnexusBulkSyncResponse);
>       Mockito.when(file.getAbsolutePath()).thenReturn("testpath");
>       String requestId = "req-1";
>       JsonObject uploadRequest = new JsonObject();
>       uploadRequest.put("requestId", requestId);
>       vertx.eventBus().consumer("test-bus", (Message<A> message) -> {
>          syncClient.sendRequest(requestId, file, message);
>       });
>       vertx.eventBus().send("test-bus", uploadRequest, event -> {
>         async.complete();
>       });
>       async.await(TIMEOUT);
>  }
> ```

You may assume all variables are mocked as required.
I would like the test to invoke the `request.handler` in `sendRequest` method. Validated that the entire flow executes up to `request.end`.

Comment: Show what have you tried so far

Comment: @Coder my bad, added the test case written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it done using ArgumentCaptor.

Here's the piece of code (part of above test) which helps to achieve the above.

Declaring the ArgumentCaptor:

> ```
>  @Captor
>  private ArgumentCaptor<Handler<HttpClientResponse>> requestCaptor;
> ```

Using the captor in test:

> ```
>  vertx.eventBus().consumer("test-bus", (Message<A> message) -> {
>      syncClient.sendRequest(requestId, file, message);
>      Mockito.verify(httpClientRequest, Mockito.times(1)).handler(requestCaptor.capture());
>      Handler<HttpClientResponse> httpClientResponseHandler = requestCaptor.getValue();
>      httpClientResponseHandler.handle(httpClientResponse);
>   });
> ```

Explanation: [ArgumentCaptor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) captures the execution flow and then further execution can be triggered manually with desired arguments. It works only with `Mockito.verify`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to mock the responses of that 3rd party service with Wiremock:

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass {

    private static WireMockServer wiremock;
    private Vertx vertx;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        wiremock = new WireMockServer(host, port); //configure host and port
        wiremock.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanup() {
        wiremock.stop();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup(TestContext ctx){
        //init vertx
        Async async = testContext.async();
        vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        ...
        async.complete();
    }

    @Test
    public void mytest(TestContext testContext){
        Async async = testContext.async();
        stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/.*"))
          .willReturn(aResponse()
          .withStatus(200)
          .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
          .withBody("{}")));

        HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(...)
        client.getNow("/some-uri", response -> {
            //check response
            async.complete();
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I was looking more towards a possibility of mimicking HttpClientRequest execution flow.

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you with that approach